# MS Visual Studio "Package Load Failure" error

Tags: visual-studio-2005, visualsvn

I'm receiving "Package Load Failure" error when I open VS 2005 after I installed the latest VisualSVN (v. 1.5.2). Anyone facing this error? Is there any tool out there to help identify which package didn't load and/or help unload a specific package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the [Visual Studio SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=30402623-93ca-479a-867c-04dc45164f5b) will install the "Package Load Analyzer" package. This allows you to see what package failed to load and why.

Answer (score 0):

There should be VisualSVN log files in your temp folder (somewhat like 
"C:\Documents and Settings\\Local 
Settings\Temp\VisualSVN-2007-06-02-00-01-416.log").

Do you see anything in that file that helps?

Comment: Something about getting a newer version of Subversion client which I already have. I downloaded the latest from TortoiseSVN (v. 1.5.3)